# INVALID literal in python not being removed

Tags: python

```
import time 
start_time=time.time()
a,b,c=0,0,0              #cat a ,cat b ,mouse c
q=int(input())
arr=[]
sample=0
def func(a,b,c): 
    if(abs(c-a)<abs(c-b)): 
        return "Cat A"
    elif (abs(c-b)<abs(c-a)):
        return "Cat B"
    else: 
        return "Mouse C"
for i in range(q) :
    a=int(input())
    b=int(input())
    c=int(input())
    print(func(a,b,c))
```

i had this program and in hacker rank the input that it gave were

> 2
>
> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 3

and i was getting the correct output in my text editor but in hacker rank it showed

> invalid literal for int() with base 10

please tell what to do

Comment: "1 2 3 4 5 3" if there are 6 values, why are you taking only 3 of them as input?

Comment: please see now @Abhi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
```

It will work if 3 values are entered in different lines/prompts. In your case, you might want to use

```
a,b,c = map(int, input().split())
```

In competitive programming, a common practice is to store all inputs in a list, and then process that list. You can also try this approach, which is something like

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
your_function(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see you are inputting multiple values delimited by space, so you can split and show a list of integer items:

```
a = [int(x) for x in a.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

The code works fine but the way you are giving input is wrong.

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
```

`input()` takes values till it encounters a new line.
These lines need input separated by space, but you are probably giving it like:

```
1 2 3
```

Rather than:

```
1
2
3
```

Therefore the space present between the input throws error!
You can rather split the input by the following:

```
a, b, c = input().split()
```

Since input() takes input as a string, you'll have to convert it into int.

```
a, b, c = int(a), int(b), int(c)
```

Comment: "space present between the input throws error" The space also exists between ```1 2 3```

Comment: Its called new line in the latter one. input() takes values till it encounters a new line.

Comment: It was a valid answer since it rectified what the person who posted this answer was doing. Rather than changing his code, it would have worked perfectly. Anyways, edited.